# Keep same table structure but only MAX values

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: brick_table]

Hi all,
How can I, in the most efficient way,  keep only the records with the max weights values per color but same table structure (all columns) without using subselects ?
I was trying: max(over partition by colour) but I don't know how to condition further. (not sure if this is the best way)
Thanks!

Comment: It turns out you need to delete records that are less than the maximum value?

Comment: These requirements are not clear at all. Do you need some additional aggregated table? the colour and brick_id are unique and it will update every time with max weight? What is the date column ?

Comment: The most efficient way would mean to post your data as TEXT (or as DDL/DML), and not as picture (see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: what values should be returned for the colour `red`? (There is `BRICK_ID` with value 5 and 4, but which one do you want/need?, same for `WEIGHT` and `Date`)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to delete those rows:
In CTE Block the record with 1 value shows `MAX` weight. So When Joining main table with CTE adding extra condition `RN = 1`, cause that other value that RN is not equal 1 become `NULL`; and there are the record should be deleted and max value remain in table.

```
With CTE As (
 Select BRICK_ID, Row_Number() Over (Partition By color, order by Weight DESC) RN
  From table_name
  )
DELETE tbl
  FROM CTE 
    RIGHT JOIN table_name tbl ON CTE.BRICK_ID = tbl.BRICK_ID AND RN = 1
  WHERE CTE.BRICK_ID IS NULL
```

And if you want to move the records with max weight to another table with same structure, use this one:

```
With CTE As (
 Select BRICK_ID, Row_Number() Over (Partition By color, order by Weight DESC) RN
  From table_name
  )
Select tbl.*
into new_table_name
  FROM CTE 
    INNER JOIN table_name tbl ON CTE.BRICK_ID = tbl.BRICK_ID
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can do that without adding a column which was not in the original set?

Comment: My query does not add any column to table. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete rows and keep the max Weight for each colour group by using an updatable CTE, such as:

```
with delme as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by colour order by weight desc) rn
  from Yourtable
)
delete from delme where rn > 1;
```